# How do I unsign a session variable most efficiently?

Tags: php, session

I'm currently working on a school project, where I am supposed to access a database from some application of my choosing (webpage w/ php in this case), and I've encountered an issue. in my function NewUser(), once the account is created, there is a message that pops up in the login window (it's in swedish, so don't worry about that hehe), but the problem is this:
considering i've used sessions, the message will always be there, and will never be removed until I restart the session somehow (in this case, restart the server), which is not really optimal.

I'd like, for example, to have the message deleted everytime the page is reloaded, if that is at all possible?

Any help you can give is helpfull, and i'm merely wondering what the best method for closing a session, when the page is reloaded is?

Best regards,
Victor

```
<?php
session_start();

ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting( E_ALL );

include('connect.php');

function NewUser()
{
   global $email;
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
   $pnumber = $_POST['pnumber'];
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

   global $mysqli;
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO persons (firstname, lastname, pnumber, age, email, pwd)
                            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
   $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $firstname, $lastname, $pnumber, $age, $email, $password);
   $stmt->execute();
   if ($mysqli)
   {
     $_SESSION['accountCreated'] = "Ditt konto har skapats, du kan nu logga in!";
     header("Location:index.php");
     exit();
   }
   else
   {
       echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>
       window.alert('Oj, det blev något fel i registreringen! Försök igen');
       window.location = 'index.php';
       </script>");
      exit();
   }
 }

function SignUp()
  {
    if(!empty($_POST['email']))
  {
  global $mysqli;
  $query = ("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE email = ?");
  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))
  {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $countRows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
  }

  if($countRows < 1)
  {
    $_SESSION['emailExistsError'] = "";
    $_SESSION['message'] = "success";
    NewUser();
  }
   else
  {
    $_SESSION['accountCreated'] = "";
    $_SESSION['emailExistsError'] = "Denna mejladdressen har redan använts!";
    $_SESSION['message'] = "error";
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit();
  }

}
}
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $close = false;

    if(empty($_POST["firstname"]))
    {
      $_SESSION['fnameError'] = "Du måste fylla i ditt förnamn!";
      $close = true;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['fnameError'] = "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST["lastname"]))
    {
      $_SESSION['lnameError'] = "Du måste fylla i ditt efternamn!";
      $close = true;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['lnameError'] = "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
      $_SESSION['emailError'] = "Du måste fylla i din e-mail!";
      $close = true;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['emailError'] = "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
      $_SESSION['passwordError'] = "Du måste fylla i ett lösenord!";
      $close = true;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['passwordError'] = "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST["pnumber"]))
    {
      $_SESSION['pnumberError'] = "Du måste fylla i ditt personnummer!";
      $close = true;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['pnumberError'] = "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST["age"]))
    {
      $_SESSION['ageError'] = "Du måste fylla i din ålder!";
      $close = true;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['ageError'] = "";
    }

    if($close == true) {
      header("Location:index.php");
      exit();
    } else {
      SignUp();
    }
  }
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, simply use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

`unset($_SESSION['message']);`

If you want to remove ALL session data (which I don't think you want), you can use `session_destroy()` or `session_unset()` depending on your intent.

Comment: Alright, seems easy enough. Okey, is there a way to implement that within a function that does that every time the page is refreshed or otherwise?

Comment: You probably don't need a function for it. You can just unset immediately after printing out your message.

Comment: But if I use unset immediately afterwards, the message will never be displayed?

Comment: @Marante : What do you mean by the message will never be displayed?

Comment: Nevermind, I just went full retard... Thanks for the help guys, it works fine now!